# How do sex biased genes evolve?

Tags: genetics, gene-expression, drosophila, sex-determination

I am wondering how do genes become sex-biased? that is, how does a gene evolve expression which is regulated in a sex-specific manner (assuming no effect from sex-limited Y/W chromosomes).

I understand that gene duplication can lead to two sex-limited genes, the derived being expressed in one sex and the ancestral being expressed in the other.

**Can the sex determining cascade cause sex-biased expression of a single locus?** My thinking is that upstream differences between males and females might bring about regulatory opportunity to loci under sexually antagonistic selection over expression level. For example, if males favour upregulation in a locus, males who evolve some kind of transcription factor affecting that locus which responds to male-specific isoforms of DSX (in *Drosophila*), which could then cause the antagonistically selected locus to be more highly expressed in males without producing a negatively selected correlated response in females.

Is this correct? Are there other ways?

(Note: I'm looking for a clear explanation of the mechanics behind sex biased gene expression. *Drosophila* examples would be of particular worth)